# I want to socialite google & facebook in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I want to add socialite for google and facebook on my website e.g if user wants to login to my website from his/her facebook or google account, it should allow this, and his record should save to my database after login.
I visited "https://laravel.com/docs/4.2", but that failed to help me.
Then
I visited "https://laravel.com/docs/5.3" for help, I have also done "composer require laravel/socialite" etc process which is mostly use in laravel 5.1 to 5.3 but it was giving errors. YouTube videos also show it working, but only for Laravel 5.1 to 5.3. How do I use socialite with Laravel 4.2?

Comment: "This document didn't help" and "it was giving errors" are not specific problem statements we can help with. Have a look at the [help] for the kinds of question we encourage, and tips on how to get the most from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Facebook SDK for PHP?

It works well, and is not hard to implement if you're only concerned with logging in. This will give you a callback for when users login or sign in. This is the same as Google+.